# What should be the SQL query for this?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose:

> `Customers {CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, City, Tel, Fax}`
>
> `Orders {OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, OrderValue}`
>
> "Give the list of customers fulfilling the following condition: value of ***each order*** from the given customer exceeds $10,000."

[image]

[image]

This query doesn't look correct to me:

```
select cc.CustomerID, cc.CustomerName, tt.OrderValue
from Customers cc,
(select CustomerID, OrderValue
from Orders
where OrderValue > 10000) tt
where cc.CustomerID = tt.CustomerID;
```

[image: Or, is it?]

The answer should be: **Pixoboo**.

Comment: Your condition says *each* order from the customer, does that mean that all orders from the customer must be above 10.000? Because then you can do an NOT EXISTS and in that select orders below 10.000.

Comment: Your query would return all customer with an ordervalue > 10000, not with **all** ordervalues > 10000. You'll have to make a comparison with count(total) and count(ordervalue > 10000), and only return the customer if both counts are equal.

Comment: So there are 2 conditions (1) at least one order (2) no orders less than or equal to $10,000

Comment: the problem with your query is that is retrieves all combinations of customer/their order that are above 10 000 - ignoring the possible existence of other, lower-amount orders. Note that you filter these out at the `from` stage - so they can't play a role in further calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if each ordeer exceeds 10000, then the smallest one must do so. So, perhaps this is the easier way:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers  
WHERE CustomerID IN 
   (SELECT CustomerID 
   FROM Orders 
   GROUP BY CustomerID  
   HAVING min(OrderValue)>10000)
```

Bonus: it avoids hairy problems with `NOT IN` and `NULLs`.

Comment: shouldn't compile, coz, there is no `OrderValue` in `Customers`.

Comment: ah, sorry, I copied part of your query. Edited. For future reference, it really helps people if you set up a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com), that way people can test their solutions before posting

Comment: Aggregate in subquery? How is this better than a NOT IN?

Comment: With `NOT IN` you have to be careful of `NULLs` in the subquery.

Comment: I can see that HAVING is the way to go, but not convinced you need a subquery - think a JOIN would work.

Comment: Well, the only way I can figure it out with a `JOIN` would either require subquery in the `JOIN` (same thing) or some ugly `anti-join`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  select cc.CustomerID, cc.CustomerName, tt.OrderValue as OrderValue
   from Customers cc, Orders tt
   where cc.CustomerID = tt.CustomerID and tt.OrderValue >10000  
   Group by cc.CustomerID, cc.CustomerName, tt.OrderValue
```

Comment: yours query as to check what you are missing in your condition

Comment: Added some pics in the question.

Comment: Only pixoboo, why not Eazzy as both have greater than 10000

Comment: Eazzy has one value equal to 10,000. I need to find values that exceed 10,000.

Comment: No sorry, it would select customers who have a mix of low and high value orders and produce a separate row for each different order value

Answer (score 1):

The present SQL query will fetch those records as well who have placed orders in less than 10,000 and more than 10,000.

Given that you have retrieve the list of customers who has always placed an order for more than 10,000,  I would always approach this with the negation condition as this will filter all the records who have at any given point of time placed a lower value order.

Query is:

```
  Select DISTINCT  CC.CUSTOMERNAME
    from CUSTOMER CC
    WHERE CC.CUSTOMERID NOT IN 
(Select DISTINCT CUSTOMERID from ORDERS where ORDERVALUE<10000)
```

Let me know if this answers your questions

Comment: Please validate at your end

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there aren't enough answers to this question, here's one without using a subquery:-

```
Select C.CustomerId,count(C.CustomerId),count(OrderValue)
from
Customers C
inner join
Orders o
on o.CustomerId=C.CustomerId
group by C.CustomerId
having min(OrderValue)>10000
and count(*)=count(OrderValue)
```

The last line is optional and could be included if you wanted to exclude any customers with a null OrderValue.

Here's a way of doing it with joins only:-

```
select distinct C.CustomerId
from
Customers C
inner join
Orders o
on o.CustomerId=C.CustomerId
and o.OrderValue>10000
left outer join 
(
  select distinct CustomerId
  from Orders
  where OrderValue<=10000
 ) t1 
 on C.CustomerId=t1.CustomerId
 where t1.CustomerId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderValue
FROM Customers  WHERE CustomerID NOT IN(
SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders  
WHERE OrderValue <= 10000)
```

Comment: Doesn't even compile.

Comment: still shouldn't compile, coz, there is no `OrderValue` in `Customers`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the given `CustomerID`, that it does NOT have any orders that is below the threshold.

For the first try, I would go with NOT EXISTS (or NOT IN) and a subselect. Later you could rework it to a fancy join.

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerId NOT IN
    (SELECT CustomerId FROM Orders WHERE OrderValue <= 10000);
```

Comment: And what is the problem with it? Please set up an sqlfiddle so we can work on your actual setup.

Comment: Added some pics in the question.

Comment: Sorry, then its `<= 10000`, I forgot the "exceeds" part. Check out this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c1bca/2

Answer (score 0):

If looking for individual orders that exceed 10k, than try using `left outer join`:

```
select cc.CustomerID, cc.CustomerName, ods.OrderValue
from Customers cc left outer join Orders ods
on cc.CustomerID = ods.CustomerID
where OrderValue > 10000
```

If looking for total sum orders that exceed 10k, than try using `left outer join` plus `having` condition:

```
select cc.CustomerID, cc.CustomerName, ods.OrderValue
from Customers cc left outer join Orders ods
on cc.CustomerID = ods.CustomerID
group by cc.CustomerID, cc.CustomerName, ods.OrderValue
having sum(OrderValue) > 10000
```

Comment: Are you trying to find all orders where the sum total of orders for a customer exceeds 10k?

Comment: Added some pics in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is more standerd way to get those results. i used sub query to get those results..

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,OrderValue
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID
                     FROM Orders
                     WHERE OrderValue > 10000
                    )
```

for more details refer this site.. 
[click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)